# How to properly formulate the objective function and constraints for an ERM linear program in R?

Tags: r, linear-programming

So I am having an issue I tried on my own but it seemed to no avail. It concerns the ERM (Empirical Risk Minimization) algorithm, used in [Ban and Rudin's paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/10.1287/opre.2018.1757) for solving a Newsvendor problem, which consists of the following linear problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi6ZP.png)

In the problem above, we are looking for the vector q(q<sup>1</sup>,...,q<sup>p</sup>) (no powers, it is just indexing). The authors have introduced two dummy variables u<sub>i</sub> and o<sub>i</sub> to transform the function (x)+ which is the max(0,x) into a linear expression.
b and h are constants given for backorder and holding costs, n stands for the total number of observations, p stands for the number of features considered, d<sub>i</sub> stands for the value of the demand in period i and x<sub>i</sub><sup>j</sup> stands for the value of the feature j in period i.

I want to solve this problem in R for a specific dataset, where n=100 and p=2. The dataset offers values for the demands and two other features (Budget and GDP) for each period i=1,2,...,100.
In that case, my problem would be like:

Decision variables: q<sup>1</sup>,q<sup>2</sup>,u and o where i=1,2,...,100

Objective function: min (1/100)*( sum (b * u)+(h * o)) where i=1,2,...,100

Constraints:

1. u>=0, for all i=1,2,...,100
2. o>=0, for all i=1,2,...,100
3. u+q<sup>1</sup>+(q<sup>2</sup>*GDP[i])>=Sales[i], for all i=1,2,...,100
4. o-q<sup>1</sup>-(q<sup>2</sup>*GDP[i])>=-Sales[i], for all i=1,2,...,100

I want to solve the above formulated problem in R, so far, I tried the following:

```
install.packages("lpSolve")
library(lpSolve)
Sales_data <- read_csv("sales_data.csv")
b = 100
h = 1
Sales <- Sales_data$Sales
AdBudget <- Sales_data$AdBudget
GDP <- Sales_data$GDP
```

I am not sure how to properly formulate the objective function and the constraints, I would appreciate your help or hints very much.

Comment: Maybe ask here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/